# Where are the rest of my files?

Tags: macos

I bought a backup drive and copied all of the files in "all my files" from both of my user accounts into it, yet i checked the drive storage and there is significantly more space being used by the primary drive (150 to 200 gb more). Where are the rest of my files?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different. All my files is a smart search - it’s kind of like a mailed flyer that hilights specials at the grocery store for the week. Not all the items are on the same shelf in the store  - it’s a collection of files that meet recent use criteria - not an actual folder that hold files. What specifically are you trying to accomplish or measure? We might need an edit to help you out.

Comment: where is this "all my files" you refer to?

Comment: bmike trying to backup all of my files without everything else that time machine backs up